# Can you make a bool return 1 if a variable is of a certain type?

Tags: c++

```
class A {
protected:
  int a;

public:
  int getA() const
  {
    return a;
  }
};

class B : public A 
{
private:
  int b;

public:
  int getB() const
  {
    return b;
  }
};

class C 
{
private:
  int c;
  A* obj;

public:
  C()
  {
    obj = new A[5];// obj is initialized with some values in the constructor, but i won't do it here
  }

  void f() 
  {
    c += obj[0].getB();
  }

  ~C()
  {
    delete obj;
  }
};
```

The problem I am facing right now is that i want the `f` function to add to the variable `c` the value of `b` from the object `obj[0]` if the type of `obj[0]` is `B`. But if the `obj[0]` is `A` and not `B` I dont want anything to happen.

Is there a bool that would be `1` if a certain variable is a certain type?

I know i could overload the f function and make it take a parameter the `B` `obj[0]` and another one that takes as a paramter the `A` `obj[0]`, the last function having an empty body, but i was wondering if there is a more simple/efficient way of doing it.

I have bee asked to provide an example of where I would need this specific solution so here it is

```
class Item
{
protected:
    std::string Name;
    unsigned long long Number;
    bool Placeable;
};

class Tool : public Item
{
private:
    long double AttackDamage;
    long double AttackSpeed;
public:
    long double getAttackDamage() const
    {
        return this->AttackDamage;
    }
    long double getAttackSpeed() const
    {
        return this->AttackSpeed;
    }
};

class Mob
{
protected:
    Item* Inventory;
    unsigned long long InventorySize;
    unsigned long long MainHand;
    std::string Name;
    long double AttackDamage;
    long double AttackSpeed;
public:
    Mob(unsigned long long n)
    {
        this->AttackDamage = 1;
        this->AttackSpeed = 0.5;
        this->InventorySize = n;
        this->Inventory = new Item[this->InventorySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->InventorySize; ++i)
            this->Inventory[i] = e; // e in empty slot, like a 0 initializer for integers
        this->MainHand = 0;
    }
    void setStats()
    {
        this->AttackDamage += this->Inventory[this->MainHand].getAttackDamage();
        this->AttackSpeed += this->Inventory[this->MainHand].getAttackSpeed();
    }
    ~Mob()
    {
        delete Invenory;
    }

};
```

The method i need help with is void SetStats() in Mob. I want the function to only update the values of AttackDamage and AttackSpeed if the item at MainHand position is a Tool. Otherwise i dont want any updates. I could add stas to the Item class like AttackDamage and AttackSpeed and set them to 0 which would make no issue but if i would be working on a more serious project i would have more stats than AttackDamage and Speed and there would be a lot of unnecesarry memory.

This is just a fraction of the code, like not all variables are initialized and there might be some things i forgot to paste

Comment: `do` is reserved, you can't use that name.

Comment: Please make your code readable.

Comment: This example is very abstract; the real solution you choose will depend on your intentions. You can use templates, or virtual functions, or just add parameters to `do()`, but nobody can know which is best unless you make it clear what the purpose of this is.

Comment: You're probably looking for `dynamic_cast`

Comment: and why not `int getB() const { return 0; }` in `class B`?

Comment: The type of the member is `A`. Thus it is not `B`.

Comment: `obj` can never be a `B`. Maybe you wanted to use pointers instead?

Comment: The type of `obj` is `A`; variables have the type declared in the source code. Read about polymorphism and the dynamic type of objects in your favourite C++ book. (And spending time thinking about the difference between variables and objects is not a waste.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] where the type of `obj` is `A` in one case and `B` in a different case.

Comment: @eerorika wait if you have my examplde you can create A obj1; and then B obj2 = obj1; and it would still work, beacause B inherits from A, thus any method in A is in B (or overridden). So B obj2 = obj1 should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Shthephathord23 `and then B obj2 = obj1; and it would still work, beacause B inherits from A`. No. Just because B inherits from A doesn't mean that you can initialise a B from A.

Comment: @eerorika sorry, i missunderstood. I have a pointer in my example A* obj1 = new A[1];
B obj2; obj[0] = obj2; I realized my mistake i will change it in the question, i just realised how stupid I was

Comment: The type `bool` has two values: `false` and `true`. Those values can be **converted** to the integer values 0 and 1, respectively, but 0 and 1 are not values of type `bool`. So the question is more properly formed as "can a `bool` value be set to `true` if a variable has a certain type?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least one virtual function in the base class, otherwise there is no polymorphism. The canonical way is to define a virtual destructor:

```
class A {
    // ...

    virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

To use polymorphism, you can't have value types. You need pointers or references. So instead of `A obj`, you'd need to use `A* obj`. You then try to `dynamic_cast` `obj` to a `B*` pointer. If `obj` is indeed pointing to a `B`, the cast succeeds and returns a valid `B*` pointer you can use. If `obj` is not pointing to a `B`, the cast fails and returns a null pointer:

```
class C {
private:
    int c;
    A* obj;

public:
    void func()
    {
        if (auto casted_obj = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj)) {
            c += casted_obj->getB();
        }
    }
};
```